# Can I publish a "coming soon" version of my application? (e.g. information regarding the upcoming service, ability to reserve a spot)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I read the Apple submission guidelines and it states that trials, demos, or betas will be rejected. However, if I'm offering a service and it isn't ready yet, but I want to get people familiar with the name, can I release a "soft" version of the application which tells users about the upcoming service and the ability to reserve a spot?

To reiterate, I am building a service which will release sometime later this year, hopefully. However, I would like to gather interested users and give them information about it and the ability to join a mailing list, create an account, connect on social media through a simplistic app (under the same name). Is this allowed?

I would like some clarification, if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're releasing a functioning app that works, I can't see a reason why it wouldn't be approved.

However, this assumes that the app actually serves a purpose in its current state and that all you're doing is including additional info such as *Coming soon* etc.

If Apple does have an issue with the current version, you'll receive an email from iTunes Connect advising you that the App Store Review team have sent you a message and you can view and respond to it via the Resolution Centre. Typically this gives you the chance to address their concerns and, if necessary, to make changes.

Even if they didn't give you this opportunity, you can always resubmit the app once you've updated it.